# Why shouldn't if statement conditions (props) be inside curly braces in react components?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm reading the react documentation and on the "props" section they have a solution that takes a size prop and pass it inside the if statement's condition. Why don't we have "size" inside curly braces here? Shouldn't the props be inside curly braces according to JSX? I'm pretty new to React and JSX.

```
    function Avatar({ person, size }) {
  let thumbnailSize = 's';
  if (size > 90) {
    thumbnailSize = 'b';
  }
  return (
    <img
      className="avatar"
      src={getImageUrl(person, thumbnailSize)}
      alt={person.name}
      width={size}
      height={size}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simple, you are not using it in JSX.
JSX returns HTML in which you can use your variables by putting them in curly braces, however you are using it in a function.

Maybe you are confused since size is also in curly braces in parameters ?
If that's so then that's just object destructuring.

This is example of object destructuring:

```
const userDetails = {
  name: 'Prince Yadav,
  age: 26,
  location: 'New Delhi'
};

const { name, age, location } = user;

console.log(name); // Output: '"Prince Yadav'
console.log(age); // Output: 26
console.log(location); // Output: 'New Delhi'
```

```
function MyComponent({ name, age, location }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <p>{age}</p>
      <p>{location}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In short JSX is everything in return statement, but before that it's just javascript/typescript whatever you are using.

Comment: Hey thanks. Is it safe to assume that anything before the return should not be in curly braces? (I know its not the only case)

Comment: Yes, when you are in JSX writing HTML and the moment you type '{' (open curly braces) is the moment you start using Javascript, so curly braces are a way to "break" out of HTML code and start typing Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In JSX, when you are using curly braces {}, it is used for embedding JavaScript expressions. In the case of the Avatar component you provided, the size prop is not inside curly braces because it is being used as a variable directly in the JSX markup.

The JSX syntax allows you to use curly braces for embedding JavaScript expressions when you need to evaluate or reference a JavaScript variable, expression, or function. However, not every use of a prop or variable in JSX requires curly braces.

****In your example:****

```
<img
  className="avatar"
  src={getImageUrl(person, thumbnailSize)}
  alt={person.size}
  width={size}
  height={size}
/>
```

Here, width={size} and height={size} are using the size prop directly in JSX, and it doesn't need to be wrapped in curly braces because it's a simple variable reference.

On the other hand, if you had something more complex like conditional rendering or a JavaScript expression, then you would use curly braces.
For example:

```
<img
  className="avatar"
  src={getImageUrl(person, thumbnailSize)}
  alt={person.size}
  width={size > 90 ? size : 90}
  height={size > 90 ? size : 90}
/>
```

In the above case, the width and height values are determined by a JavaScript expression (size > 90 ? size : 90), so they are wrapped in curly braces.

In summary, you use curly braces {} in JSX when you need to embed JavaScript expressions, but for simple variable references or prop values, you can use them directly without curly braces.